# List row separator not hiding when using another view on top

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

I am using a package that hides the list view separator for iOS 14.
https://github.com/SchmidtyApps/SwiftUIListSeparator

Whenever I add another view on top of the **List**, like a simple *Divider*(), the list row separator will appear again for no reason.

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        Divider() //if I remove this divider, everything works fine
        
        List{
            ForEach(1...3, id: \.self){_ in
                
                Text("item")
                
            } .listSeparatorStyle(.none) ///the method to hide the row separator
            
        }
    }
}
```

You can try on your preview by yourself.
I have tried multiple way to hide the separator but just this one worked for me, so please do not duplicate it.

Why whenever I add another view, the separator line appear again?

Also, how I can add the **if #available(iOS 15, *)**?

```
   var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        Divider()
        
        List{
            ForEach(1...3, id: \.self){_ in
                
                Text("fdasf")
                
            }
            
            if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            else{
                .listSeparatorStyle(.none)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` instead of listSeparatorStyle()

Comment: I am trying to use if #available(iOS 15, *) but it gives me an error. How do you use the if #available(iOS 15, *) {.listRowSeparator(.hidden)} ?

Comment: Use ` .listRowSeparator(.hidden)` which is available in #available(iOS 15.0, *). Its fixed issues at me end in SwiftUI\

Comment: How I can use that on my code? I tried and it does not work for me.. how do you use the  #available(iOS 15.0, *)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Yodagama's comment, use `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)`

To use different modifiers for OS versions, pull your `List` out into a function (or its own View), and then apply the relevant modifier…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            list()
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        } else{
            list()
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
    }
    
    func list() -> some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1...3, id: \.self){_ in
                Text("fdasf")
            }
        }
    }
}
```